# How can I retrieve a Perl hash value only if its key exists?

Tags: perl, hash

Code:

```
%a =  ( 1 => "ONE" , 
        2 => "TWO" ,
        3 => " Three", ); 
$test_value = 1 ;

foreach $key (sort(keys %a)) {
    if  ($key == $test_value ) { 
        print $a{$key}; 
    }

}
```

I just want to achieve the same operation in very short way.  Is there any shortcut for this?

Comment: Wow, it's like I've traveled back in time to 1996!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
print $a{$test_value};
```

Comment: if the $a{$test_value} is not defined Wat will be return ?

Comment: @Krish: The return value will be `undef`.

Comment: you can test:
 if( exists $a{$test_value} ) {
  print $a{$test_value}; // will warn if it exists and is null
 }

Comment: the "exists" keyword was what he was looking for, answer is in the question ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
print $a{$test_value} if exists $a{$test_value};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
my @tt = map {$_, if $_ == $test_value} keys %a;
print "\n @tt";
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is an array of hashes you first have to go to that array and then access the element by its key value.

```
print "${@{$h{LMN}{xyz}{c}}[2]}{Number}";
```

Comment: looks - at best, can't really judge its content :-) - as a comment to another answer vs. an answer to the original question. What is it?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the **$test_value** would be a variable of some sort you might want something like

```
if( defined( $a{$test_value} ) ){
    print $a{$test_value};
}
```

or even

```
print $a{$test_value} if( defined( $a{$test_value} ) )
```

depending on how readable you want it :-)

Comment: get rid of all your parenthesis on the last one for the BEST readability.

Comment: In this case you probably want to check here if $a{$test_value} is defined - but more generally this could return false if the value was undef. Use exist to check for this case, which will check if the key exists in the hash, not if the value is defined.

Comment: You want to use 'exists', not 'defined' , or autovivification will take place and the value will start to exist.

Answer (score -2):

Readable? :)

This oneliner will give you the same thing:

```
defined $a{$testvalue} and print $a{$testvalue};
```

Comment: You want to use 'exists', not 'defined' , or autovivification will take place and the value will start to exist.

Comment: No, autovivification only happens when you access nested values. $a{$foo}{$bar} will autovivify $foo even if it doesn't exist, and even if it's only checking for existence/definedness.